# launching Protractor fails and exited with error code #199"

Tags: unit-testing, angular, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am a new Protractor. I am trying to run a sample unit test on my first Angular2 application.

my conf.js file has :

```
exports.config = { 
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:3000/login', 
    specs: ['todo-spec.js'], 
    capabilities: { 
       'browserName': 'chrome', 
        chromeOnly:true , 
        directConnect: true } 
    };
```

2.my 'todo-spec.js' file has :

```
describe('Authentication capabilities', function() {
  var email = element(by.id('inputusername'));
  var password = element(by.id('inputPassword'));
  var loginButton = element(by.class('btn-success'));


it('should redirect to the login page if trying to load protected page while not authenticated', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:3000/login');
    loginURL = browser.getCurrentUrl();
    email.sendKeys("demo");
    password.sendKeys("demo");
    loginButton.click();

  });  
 });
```

but when i try to run the protractor by the following command "protractor "filepath\conf.js",

Getting " E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199" error.

can anyone please let me know, where I'm doing mistake?

Comment: could you pls elaborate where i have done mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,` in my config file.

also, commented `"seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"`

so right now my code is like this,and working.

```
exports.config = {
//seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
//directConnect: true,
specs: ['todo-spec.js'],

capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',

},
useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
framework: 'jasmine'
};
```

Comment: how are you able to connect with the browser without using seleniumAddress and directConnect?

Comment: i think when i run `protractor 'path\conf.js'` it automatically starts selenium standalone server and starts the browser as well, once the test is done, it shuts down selenium server. :)

Comment: Add useAllAngular2AppRoots: true works for me. Thanks. But I need keep "seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have the latest JDK and JRE are installed (Selenium somewhat seems to have dependencies with them).This was something unexpected that I found the hard way after finding that the server was not being initialised while running Protractor test tasks with gulp.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. Installing the Java Runtime solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. Eventually, I got the solution after updating the chrome latest version.
I was using the Chrome version `79.0` and I have updated it to the latest version `80.0.3987.87` (Official Build) (64-bit).

Just try updating the latest chrome version as it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
//directConnect: true,
specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},

framework: 'jasmine'
};
```

if you want to use directConnect, uncomment it and comment the seleniumAddress

Comment: I just tried this. but getting this error now - 'E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135'

Comment: @Sarav did you start the selenium server before executing the config file?

Comment: Hey danny, yes its resolved, but I had to use "useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,"

Answer (score 1):

Check that your browser has the latest version (in my case this error disappeared after Chrome become latest version)

Answer (score 1):

you have to update your chromedriver. Might be that you're locked in an older version of webdriver-manager that doesn't download chromedriver 78 for you. Doing `npm install -f protractor` should help for that.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. Eventually, I got the solution after downgrading the node  version to 11.15.0. I was using the node version 12.0.0.

Now i have 11.15.0 and protractor tests with chrome works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working earlier and not now (May be after PC reboot or restart) than just update the webdriver by command in terminal

> webdriver-manager update

It should work fine.

Even if wont work, Uninstall and reinstall the browser. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my chrome browser version is 96.0 something initially when I upgrade it to 97.0.4692.71 then the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

this happens when multiple user using same remote machine followed by same Selenium server.
As the other person quits the server, then def u will get it.

To resolve this: change the Selenium server address from regular 4444 to 9999 or any

This will work